# @EmbeddedId primary key , object not managed after persist

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity with Composote key on the following tables:
1- User
2- Department

I'm using Spring Data to save the entity via the save method of JpaRepository , now if I update on the entity after the save in the same transaction the update doesn't happen , this is done by updating a field using the setter method in the same @Transactional.

it seems the entity that I saved ( new entity ) is not managed. is that because the entity primar key is not Long/Integer ?

---

**Update:**
if I use the entity returned from the save it works , I think because the primary key is not null , Spring will consider it as merge instead of persist , hence the entity that used to save is not the same as the one returned.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Data
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class User{

 @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;


  private String username;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "department")
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Department {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
  private String name;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "COURSE")
@Data
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Course  {

  @EmbeddedId private CourseId courseId;
  
  private String name;
}



@Embeddable
@Data
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CourseId implements Serializable {

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
  private User user;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID")
  private Department department;
}


public interface CourseRepository  extends JpaRepository<Course, CourseId> {


}


@Transactional
public void createCourse(){
    
    User user=userRepository.findOneByName("user1");
    Department department=departmentRepository.findOneByName("department");
    CourseId courseId=new CourseId(user,department);
    Course course=new Course();
    course.setCourseId(courseId);
    courseRepository.save(course);// here it works
    course.setName("test"); // this doesn't update


}
```

Comment: Please show the code instead of a description of the code.

Comment: @M.Deinum Please check , updated with code

Comment: You already figured it out yourself, always use the entity returned from the `save` method.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for it to not being working is that the primary key is not null , hence Spring will consider the entity as merge and not persist. in merge a new managed entity is returned hence I need to use the returned entity from save :

```
course= courseRepository.save(course);
 course.setName("test");
```